# qt query mysql, error:QODBC3: unable to fetch first

Tags: mysql, qt, odbc

I was successfully connected to mysql,by when i query from mysql,there is a error: QODBC3: unable to fetch first.How do I fix this？

there is my code:

```
QSqlQuery MySqlOperator::getRecord() {
    bool open = mysqlDb.open();

    QSqlQuery query = mysqlDb.exec("select * from sys_user");

    mysqlDb.close();

    while(query.next()) {
        int id = query.value(0).toInt();
        QString name = query.value("username").toString();
    }

    QString error = query.lastError().text();

    return query;
}
```

my os is windows10,qt is 5.15,mysql is 8.0.13 in centos8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I noticed that you use ```mysqlDb.close()```.  Isn't it required to be opened in order for ```query.next()``` to work?